# IntMap changes type after innocent mapping

Tags: collections, scala, dictionary, lambda, immutability

consider this piece of code:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.r0-b20100714201327 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_20).
scala> val a = IntMap((1,1))
a: scala.collection.immutable.IntMap[Int] = IntMap((1,1))
scala> a.map(x => (x._1,x._2 + 1))
res23: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map((1,2))
```

header of IntMap.map says this

```
 def   map  [B]  (f: ((Int, T)) ⇒ B)  : immutable.IntMap[B]
```

[use case] Builds a new collection by applying a function to all elements 
of this immutable integer map.

How should I construct the lambda to return IntMap?

Comment: Here's the (fixed) bug: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3603

Comment: Side comment: you can use `a mapValues { _ + 1 }`, although it exhibits the same buggy behavior with an IntMap.

Comment: It seems this bug was fixed in trunk but *not* in 2.8.0.final. And to correct my previous comment, this behavior is expected for `mapValues` because it returns a map view rather than a new map. See http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/IntMap-bug-td2524621.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Scala 2.8, I get

```
scala> a.map(x => (x._1,x._2 + 1))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IntMap[Int] = IntMap((1,2))
```